# Nnet with Caret in R

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, multinomial, nnet

I am having a ton of trouble trying to solve a multinomial classification equation in R. I am using the nnet and caret package to solve this. A dataset is below and this is reproducible:

```
df

PARTNER2      ADV
       A    Gamma
       B    Gamma
       C    Gamma
       D    Gamma
       D    Gamma
       E    Gamma
       F    Gamma
       G    Gamma
       F    Gamma
       F    Gamma
       H    Gamma
       I    Gamma
       F    Gamma
       J    Gamma
       D    Gamma
       E    Beta
       K    Beta
       D    Beta
       D    Beta
       E    Beta
       F    Beta
       L    Beta
       F    Beta
       F    Beta
       M    Beta
       F    Beta
       E    Beta
       N    Zeta
       J    Zeta
       N    Zeta
       O    Zeta
       D    Zeta
       P    Zeta
       Q    Zeta
       D    Zeta
       F    Zeta
       L    Zeta
       F    Zeta 
       F    Zeta
       D    Zeta
       D    Zeta
       L    Alpha
       L    Alpha
       R    Alpha
       E    Alpha
       F    Alpha
       D    Alpha
       D    Alpha
       N    Alpha
```

From here, I am using the caret package to train the data and use the model to predict the probabilities of `ADV` showing up when `PARTNER2` appears. I get an error though at the end which I just can't seem to solve.

```
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=df$ADV, p=0.75, list=FALSE)   # We wish 75% for the trainset 

train.set <- df[inTrain,]
test.set  <- df[-inTrain,]
nrow(train.set)/nrow(test.set) # should be around 3

model <- train(ADV ~ ., train.set, 
               method='nnet', 
               trace = FALSE)

prediction <- predict(model, newdata=test.set[-2], type="prob")
```

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :
> factor PARTNER2 has new levels I, J

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Comment: Works fine on win7, R_33.2, caret_6.0.73, e1071_1.6.8. Good luck!

Comment: your  `test.set` probably contains unseen levels  of `PARTNER2` from the `train.set`. You should use stratified sampling to split your data.

Comment: It worked for me by changing it from read_csv to read.csv. But it doesn't work when I make a table for comparison. `table(prediction, test.set$ADV)` Does that part work for you?

Comment: Also let's say that this dataset was 5000 rows and about 700 categorical predictor variables. How long does it usually take to run this? I've been waiting for about 20 min now and not sure if I should try something else. When I stop it, no warnings come up making me think that it's just taking awhile

Comment: I'm happy to send someone the full dataset but it is too large to put on here.

Comment: I just ran the code and it works for me... R 3.5.0